# How to pass multiple Date formats in DateTimeFormatter using Scala

Tags: java, scala, date-parsing, date

I have three date formats: YYYY-MM-DD, DDMMYYYY, MMDDYYYY this is how I pass date format in Spark to parse.

```
scala> val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[MMddyyyy][yyyy-MM-dd][yyyyMMdd]")
formatter: java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter = [Value(MonthOfYear,2)Value(DayOfMonth,2)Value(YearOfEra,4,19,EXCEEDS_PAD)][Value(YearOfEra,4,19,EXCEEDS_PAD)'-'Value(MonthOfYear,2)'-'Value(DayOfMonth,2)][Value(YearOfEra,4,19,EXCEEDS_PAD)Value(MonthOfYear,2)Value(DayOfMonth,2)]
```

For format MMddyyyy it's working

```
scala> LocalDate.parse("10062019",formatter)
res2: java.time.LocalDate = 2019-10-06
```

For format yyyyMMdd it's working

```
scala> LocalDate.parse("2019-06-20",formatter)
res3: java.time.LocalDate = 2019-06-20
```

For format yyyyMMdd, it's giving me an error

```
scala> LocalDate.parse("20190529",formatter)
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20190529' could not be parsed: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 20
  at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1920)
  at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1855)
  at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400)
  ... 66 elided
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 20
  at java.time.temporal.ValueRange.checkValidIntValue(ValueRange.java:330)
  at java.time.temporal.ChronoField.checkValidIntValue(ChronoField.java:722)
  at java.time.chrono.IsoChronology.resolveYMD(IsoChronology.java:550)
  at java.time.chrono.IsoChronology.resolveYMD(IsoChronology.java:123)
  at java.time.chrono.AbstractChronology.resolveDate(AbstractChronology.java:472)
  at java.time.chrono.IsoChronology.resolveDate(IsoChronology.java:492)
  at java.time.chrono.IsoChronology.resolveDate(IsoChronology.java:123)
  at java.time.format.Parsed.resolveDateFields(Parsed.java:351)
  at java.time.format.Parsed.resolveFields(Parsed.java:257)
  at java.time.format.Parsed.resolve(Parsed.java:244)
  at java.time.format.DateTimeParseContext.toResolved(DateTimeParseContext.java:331)
  at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1955)
  at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
  ... 67 more
```

If I pass 2 format yyyyMMdd, yyyy-MM-dd it's working fine

```
    scala> val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[yyyy-MM-dd][yyyyMMdd]") 
scala> LocalDate.parse("20190529",formatter)
res5: java.time.LocalDate = 2019-05-29

scala> LocalDate.parse("2019-06-20",formatter)
res6: java.time.LocalDate = 2019-06-20
```

Same as yyyy-MM-dd, mmddyyy date format

```
   scala> val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[yyyy-MM-dd][MMddyyyy]")

    scala> LocalDate.parse("10062019",formatter)
    res7: java.time.LocalDate = 2019-10-06

    scala> LocalDate.parse("2019-06-20",formatter)
    res8: java.time.LocalDate = 2019-06-20
```

Is there any way that I can pass three different formats?

Comment: What is the expected result for `09112019`? It could be 9 November or September 11.

Answer (score 1):

Java's own [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder#appendOptional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendOptional-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) can handle it without without relying on exception handling. From the documentation:

> The formatter will format if data is available for all the fields contained within it. The formatter will parse if the string matches, otherwise no error is returned.

Which means you will not have to handle the multiple cases with exceptions.

Here is an example from a real code-base where I had to do this handling:

```
def dtf: DateTimeFormatter =
  new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
   .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yy"))
   .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"))
   .toFormatter()
```

Here are two unit tests (in ScalaTest) demonstrating the usage:

```
"Short form is parsed" in {
  assert(LocalDate.parse("28/08/20", dtf) == LocalDate.of(2020, 8, 28))
}
"Long form is parsed" in {
  assert(LocalDate.parse("02/10/2020", dtf) == LocalDate.of(2020, 10, 2))
}
```

Comment: It’s like you’re answering a different question? You’re not handling any of the three formats asked about, YYYY-MM-DD, DDMMYYYY and MMDDYYYY. Apart from that it’s a good answer. BTW a shorter version of your formatter definition would be `def dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[dd/MM/yy][dd/MM/yyyy]")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can´t have in the formatter [yyyyMMdd] and [MMddyyyy] at the same time. 
My idea is to normalize so you have [yyyy-MM-dd] and [MM-dd-yyyy], instead of 3 formats .

Hope this helped

Edited:

If you don´t have a chance you can do something like this, but it´s not very pretty.

```
val formatter1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[yyyy-MM-dd][MMddyyyy]")
val formatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[yyyy-MM-dd][yyyyMMdd]")

val time = "20190529"

if (time.matches("2+\\d*")) LocalDate.parse(time,formatter2) else 
LocalDate.parse(time,formatter1)
```

Comment: Whereas in my data I have three different date formats like YYYYMMDD, MMDDYYY, YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 0):

With only the information in the question this is not possible. The string `10111213` could denote December 13, 1011 or October 11, 1213. However, assuming that your dates are always after year 1300, you’re lucky because then the `YYYY` part of the string cannot be parsed as `MMDD` becuase the month will be 13 or greater, that is, not valid. You can use this for deciding which of the formats is the correct one to use.

I would use three formatters and try them in turn:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter[] DATE_FORMATTERS = {
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMdd"),
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMdduuuu"),
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd")
};
```

With these just do:

```
    String dateString = "20190529";

    LocalDate result = null;
    for (DateTimeFormatter df : DATE_FORMATTERS) {
        try {
            result = LocalDate.parse(dateString, df);
            break;
        } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
            // Ignore; try next formatter
        }
    }
    System.out.println("" + dateString + " was parsed to " + result);
```

Output is:

> 20190529 was parsed to 2019-05-29

Let’s try the two other formats too:

> 10062019 was parsed to 2019-10-06
>
> 2019-06-20 was parsed to 2019-06-20

I recommend you add a **null check** to catch any unparseable date string and a **range check** on the parsed date so that `10111213` doesn’t slip through as valid. For example:

```
    if (result == null) {
        System.out.println(dateString + " could not be parsed");
    }
    else if (result.isBefore(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Aden")))) {
        System.out.println("Date should be in the future, was " + result);
    }
```

PS I assume a typo in the first sentence of your question:

> I have three date formats: YYYY-MM-DD, DDMMYYYY, MMDDYYYY this is how
> I pass date format in Spark to parse.

The middle format should have been YYYYMMDD (otherwise you’ve got no chance).